# Angular Updating scope variables after returning from a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the q service in one of my controllers to make sure my requests finish before binding the responses in the then clause. Now here is the tricky part. There is a directive on the page who's template updates a scope variable. This scope variable is used to switch between different parts of the response json, A selector if you will. I need to updated a variable set in the then clause after the page is loaded. It is set by the id added in a directive.
I can't seem to figure out an efficient way to go about updating them.

```
$scope.selector = {}; //property added from a child scope
$q.all({
     //some factory calls and assignment to properties
}).then(function(responses){
  //scope variable assignments off of the responses object.
  //some assignment that uses the selector. a[selector.id] ex.
  }, function(err){
    $log.error(err);
   }).finally(function(){
      //some setting of load params
    });
  //Then I need to update those variables set in the then based on whether or not the selector id was changed in the directive template.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you post your entire question? I'm not sure that I understand what problem you're having, or what is missing.

Comment: @azium just updated the question. Thank you!

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @zszep updated question to try and be more clear. I am  trying to updated scope variables that are set in the then clause of  the q service, outside of the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a guess here as the question isn't clear but from the looks of it, you should just save the entire set of responses on the scope and then pull out the data you need. I don't see why you are trying to update the entire response everytime you want to pull one aspect out.

```
$scope.selector = {}; //property added from a child scope
$scope.responses = {};
$q.all({
   //some factory calls and assignment to properties
}).then(function(responses){
   //scope variable assignments off of the responses object.
   //some assignment that uses the selector. a[selector.id] ex.
   $scope.responses = responses;
}, function(err){
   $log.error(err);
}).finally(function(){
  //some setting of load params
});
// Use something like $watch here and have it call a function
```

[Watchers in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) might be helpful as well.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Sorry for being pretty vague. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Not a problem. Mind marking this as solved if this is working for you?